# Problema con Switch

Tags: javascript

Tengo que hacer un script, el cual consiste en un bucle de 100 iteraciones, cuando el iterador sea múltiplo de 3 imprimir fizz, cuando sea múltiplo de 5 imprimir buzz y cuando sea múltiplo de 3 y 5 imprimir fizzbuzz. Hice este script pero no imprime nada

```js
'use strict'
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  switch (i) {
    case (i % 3 === 0):
      console.log('fizz');
      break;
    case (i % 5 === 0):
      console.log('buzz');
      break;
    case (i % 3 === 0) && (i % 5 === 0):
      console.log('fizzbuzz');
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Estás confundido en respecto a cómo funciona el `switch`, te recomiendo leer [la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), de la misma:

> La declaración switch evalúa una expresión, comparando el valor de esa
> expresión con una instancia case, y ejecuta declaraciones asociadas a
> ese case, así como las declaraciones en los case que siguen.

Esto quiere decir que si haces algo cómo

```
switch (i) {
    case (i % 3 === 0):
```

No estarías entrando al primer `case` cuando `i % 3 === 0`, si no que entrarías al primer case cuando `i === (i % 3 === 0)`. Te recomiendo usar `if/else`.

Para este caso:

```js
'use strict'
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

  if (i % 3 === 0) {
    if (i % 5 === 0) {
      console.log('fizzbuzz');
    } else {
      console.log('fizz');
    }
  } else if (i % 5 === 0) {
    console.log('buzz');
  } else {
    console.log(i);
  }
}
```

Si quisieras hacerlo con `switch` de una manera poco eficiente y no recomendada (pero lo pongo para que veas la diferencia y ejemplificar el funcionamiento del `switch/case`):

```js
'use strict'
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  switch (0) {
    case (i % 3):
      console.log('fizz');
      break;
    case (i % 5):
      console.log('buzz');
      break;
    default:
      console.log(i);
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, lo voy a intentar con if

Answer (score 1):

@FranAcuna la única falla que le encuentro a tu código es que debido a que las sentencias if están anidadas nunca imprime fuzzbizz donde sí debería, por ejemplo en el numero 15, 30, 45, etc, así que lo hice así

```js
 'use strict'
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log('fizz');
    } if (i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log('buzz');
    } if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log('fizzbuzz');
    }
}
```

Comment: Tienes toda la razón Alan! También puede hacerse un `if` anidado, voy a editar mi respuesta tomando esto en cuenta.